# Black screen when booting up raspberry pi

Tags: boot, screen, raspberrypi, 23.04

(I had already asked this on the raspberry pi stack exchange but, as of now, no one has solved the problem).

I use a 4GB Raspberry Pi 4B. Recently, I switched to Ubuntu, and it had been working fine, until one day, I booted it up and the screen was black. Sometimes a glitched Ubuntu loading screen appears before a black screen, only containing a blinking text cursor which I can't interact with. I've tried using terminals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F(n)</kbd>. But, for some reason, I can't write out files that allow me to resolve the issue. I've tried modifying some lines in the `config.txt` file, like `hdmi_safe`, `hdmi_force_hotplug` and `hdmi_force_output`, but nothing works. From some of the errors, I can see that things like gnome screen manager, snapd snap, daemon and other stuff are failing. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the problem. Given that I was unable to rewrite files, I started by doing `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`. Then, I did `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and `sudo service gdm3 restart`. Immediately after that, my desktop appeared.